# React Native - Getting current time and creating a dynamic x(time)-axis?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, react-native

I just started working with React Native two weeks ago and I hit a wall.

I'm working on an IoT project that is logging things like temperature, humidity, CO levels etc..

I also decided to create an app to display these parameters inside a real-time chart. So far, I figured out how to communicate with the server and get data on demand and how to draw charts. The only problem is, how do I make the x-axis (time axis) dynamic? I want to update the graph every few seconds (let's say 5) when I make a new request for parameters to the server.

I've never done anything similar and I'm new to React so I have no idea how to handle this. I'd love if anyone could show a quick example in React Native with dynamic x-axis, even if it's with randomly generated numbers.

And oh, how do I get current time? I want it in a format like hours:minutes.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, could you post what graphing library you are using and/or how do you currently graph it? I think it's more helpful for everyone.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for a warm welcome. I'm using Victory-Native for graphing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to implement this depending on how you're getting data from the server and what library you're using to plot out data. I'll try to give as generic of an answer as I can.

Let's assume you have a function called `getXAxisValueFromServer` which will asynchronously request the value you want from your server and return it in a callback. (This is assuming your application queries data from the server periodically. If your application is reactive and receives data from the server through something like an [Rx.js observable](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/), the logic would be the same but you would put it in the observable's data callback)

To make your component render this dynamically, you need to make your component re-render whenever a new value arrives.

A React component re-renders [under exactly two conditions: when its `state` changes, and when its `props` change](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html).

Therefore, in order to have your component dynamically update, you'll need to tie your data to its `state` or its `props`.

In general, when using React, [it's a good idea to keep presentation separated from logic](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0). So the best approach to this would be to create a "smart" container component which receives data from the server and keeps that data in its `state`, and a "dumb" presentation component which renders the received data. Let's assume we have a chart which correctly plots data implemented as the `Chart` component, which receives a prop called `data`. We now want to implement a `ChartContainer` which will query the server for data periodically and update the `Chart`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { getXAxisValueFromServer } from './server-api';
import Chart from './chart';

export default class ChartContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: null };
    this.intervalHandle = null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.intervalHandle = setInterval(() => 
      getXAxisValueFromServer((data) => this.setState({ data })),
    3000); //this is just an example - here we try to update
           //the data every 3 seconds
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Chart data={this.state.data} />
    );
  }
}
```

So here, we have created an example container which will query the server for new data every 3 seconds and update the chart with the received data when the server returns it. You should be able to adapt this to your use case.

Comment: My god, this was exactly what I was looking for, I didn't know how to start. Thank you, I think I'll be able to handle this now. And by the way, I'm using Victory-Native for plotting the chart.

Comment: You're welcome! If I've been helpful, please consider [accepting my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). :)